# useEffect causing .map() error when sending post request

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

When I try adding a new post I get this error. But when I console.log({ newPost }) I see that the new obj gets added. Something is happening when I try setting it in setPost({ newPost }).
[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import axios from "axios"

const Users = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPosts = async () => {
      const { data: post } = await axios.get(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
      )
      setPosts(post)
    }
    getPosts()
  }, [])

  const handlePost = async () => {
    const obj = {
      title: "foo",
      body: "bar",
      userId: 1,
    }
    const { data: post } = await axios.post(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
      obj
    )
    const newPost = [post, ...posts]
    setPosts({ newPost })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>List of all Posts</h1>
      <button onClick={() => handlePost()}>Post new title</button>
      <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Users
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are calling `setPosts` with an object when you mean it to be an array.

Replace

```
setPosts({ newPost })
```

With

```
setPosts( newPost )
```

This part doesn't really matter, but I would say that when dealing with async methods it's a better practice to setState with a function of the previousState rather than accessing the previous state directly.

```
setPosts((posts) => [post, ...posts])
```

Answer (score 0):

posts state variable is expected to be an Array, so there's no need to set it inside an object. Change setPosts({ newPost }) to setPosts(newPost). It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I run the code with the error in my pc so there are some errors.
But I changed setPosts(newPost).
So it is working very well.
If we avoid these errors, we should be familiar with React Hooks